GCP Filestore read performance is highly variable
I have an application running in GKE. The application reads files from GCP Filestore mounted to pods using PV & PVC. The application can scale from 0 to 800 instances and all will read data from same Filestore.
The reading performance is highly variable, eg a 3 GB CSV file takes 26 seconds to 1175 seconds for different instance of same service.
The Filestore I am using is Basic SSD and GKE node are c2d-highmem-56 Machine Type.
I have checked below and it does not seems to be issue

Read operation not getting throttled due to SSD IOPS or Throughput limit
The node ingress not getting throttled either

I am not sure what to check further to be able to understand and solve the issue
